# Calculate Cohen's d in different groups in R

Tags: r, purrr

I have a data frame from 4 participants (identified through `id`) with variables `a` and `b` that were measured in three different times:

- `pre`
- `post1`
- `post2`

And I need to calculate the effect size (Cohen's d) of the changes between:

- `pre` to `post1`
- `post1` to `post2`

On each one of the variables (`a` and `b`).

Is there a way I can use `purrr::map` to calculate it?

**Data:**

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(
  vars = rep(letters[1:2], 12),
  value = sample(1:100, 24),
  phase = rep(factor(c("pre","post1","post2"), levels = c("pre","post1","post2")),4)
)
```

In my **expected output**, I calculate first the % change, and then I get the mean of it. Finally, my last column `d` is the effect size. Code to generate it:

```
library(effsize)

## Calculate Effect Size for `a` in `pre` - `post1`

a1 <- df %>% 
  filter(vars == "a" & phase != "post2") %>% 
  mutate(phase = fct_drop(phase)) %>%
  cohen.d(value ~ phase, data = ., paired = T) %>% 
  .$estimate

## Calculate Effect Size for `a` in `post1` - `post2`

a2 <- df %>% 
  filter(vars == "a" & phase != "pre") %>% 
  mutate(phase = fct_drop(phase)) %>%
  cohen.d(value ~ phase, data = ., paired = T) %>% 
  .$estimate

## Calculate Effect Size for `b` in `pre` - `post1`

b1 <- df %>% 
  filter(vars == "b" & phase != "post2") %>% 
  mutate(phase = fct_drop(phase)) %>%
  cohen.d(value ~ phase, data = ., paired = T) %>% 
  .$estimate

## Calculate Effect Size for `b` in `post1` - `post2`

b2 <- df %>% 
  filter(vars == "b" & phase != "pre") %>% 
  mutate(phase = fct_drop(phase)) %>%
  cohen.d(value ~ phase, data = ., paired = T) %>% 
  .$estimate

# Mutate eff sizes to data frame
df %>% 
  spread(phase, value) %>% 
  mutate("pre - post1" = (post1/pre-1)*100, "post1 - post2" = (post2/post1-1)*100) %>%  # calculate % change
  select(-pre, -post1, -post2) %>%  
  gather("phase", "pct_change", 3:4) %>%
  group_by(phase, vars) %>% 
  summarise(Mean_pct_change = mean(pct_change)) %>% # calculate mean % change
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(d = c(a2, b2, a1, b1)) # mutate effect sizes

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  phase         vars  Mean_pct_change      d
  <chr>         <fct>           <dbl>  <dbl>
1 post1 - post2 a               158.  -0.988
2 post1 - post2 b               -37.1  0.558
3 pre - post1   a               690.  -3.36 
4 pre - post1   b                11.6 -0.383
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way using `purrr`. It looks like the crux of your problem is just getting that vector of effect size estimates that you're currently saving as individual vectors, so I'm only addressing getting that vector (i.e. what you're extracting with `.$estimate`.

I saved two vectors, one of the variables you're using: `"a" "a" "b" "b"`

And one of the phases to *exclude*: `"post2" "pre"   "post2" "pre"`

The `purrr::map2_*` functions let you map along these two vectors, and for each iteration take the variable to keep and the phase to exclude. The calculation is what you already had (except swapping `.$estimate` for the possibly neater `[[`). If I used `map2`, I would get a list of numeric vectors each of length 1. But by using `map2_dbl`, you get a single numeric vector of all returned values.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(effsize)

vars <- rep(c("a", "b"), each = 2)
excl_phase <- rep(c("post2", "pre"), times = 2)

map2_dbl(vars, excl_phase, function(v, p) {
  df %>%
    filter(vars == v, phase != p) %>%
    mutate(phase = fct_drop(phase)) %>%
    cohen.d(value ~ phase, data = ., paired = T) %>%
    `[[`("estimate")
})
#> [1] -1.5663301  0.2495671 -0.2716963  0.0659341
```

Save that vector, and use it as you were before in your summarizing.

Comment: Surely `[[` isn't anything to do with magrittr given that it is a primitive function in R.

Comment: @thelatemail wow, yup, I was thinking `magrittr::extract2`, which is the alias for `[[`(

Answer (score 3):

If you can settle for base R, here is a solution.

```
library(effsize)

f <- list(c("pre", "post1"), c("post1", "post2"))

res <- lapply(split(df, df$vars), function(DF)
  sapply(f, function(g) {
    D <- subset(DF, phase %in% g)
    D$phase <- fct_drop(D$phase)
    cohen.d(value ~ phase, data = D, paired = TRUE)$estimate
  })
)

res
#$a
#[1] -1.5663301  0.2495671
#
#$b
#[1] -0.2716963  0.0659341
```

Comment: @FMM I had checked it and I have just checked it again. With your data and code the vector `c(a1, a2, b1, b2)` and my `res` give *exactly* the same results, only the forms (vector/list) are different.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I posted a comment right after saying that it worked... I don't know why it is not here anymore... anyways, using your code I made some modifications and it is working for my purpose now.. thank you very much! I am just waiting to see if anyone posts an answer using tidyverse, otherwise I will accept your answer